# Bootstrap 4 - Override breakpoints - Convert to em

Tags: bootstrap-4, sass, media-queries

I'm trying to override default Bootstrap 4 (v4.1.3) breakpoints and convert them to `ems`.

I started by overriding the `$grid-breakpoints` variable with the following:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
    xs: 0,
    sm: 36.000em,
    md: 48.000em,
    lg: 62.000em,
    xl: 75.000em
);
```

However, when I try compile I get the following error:

```
Message:
    assets/sass/vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_breakpoints.scss
Error: Incompatible units: 'px' and 'em'.
        on line 42 of assets/sass/0.vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_breakpoints.scss
>>   @return if($next, breakpoint-min($next, $breakpoints) - .02px, null);
```

It seems there is an issue with one of their mixins using `px` in it's calculations.

Any ideas for how I can fix this?

Comment: There's no a simple way w/o redefining the `_breakpoints.scss`

Comment: Yes that's the problem I wanted to avoid. It seems I have no alternative though. Just had a client complain and I realised it's because she had her OS set to scale fonts at 125% which was making the media queries behave in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to override the Bootstrap media queries, you will have no choice but to edit the Bootstrap source files. You will need to convert all values found in the `_breakpoints.scss` mixins file to `ems`.

However, proceed with caution and only do this if you have the time to test thoroughly - there is some nuance here as you will discover if you read these threads which were discussed when Bootstrap 4 was in development:

Here they basically say they will stick with `px` because of the very same issue that I had - it breaks on compilation. So, at the time, it was considered a breaking change for Bootstrap V4 and would be something to consider for V5:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/27190

Here is a lengthy discussion that talks about the Pros and Cons of using `em` units in media queries. **This is where I want to caution you** to first consider if you have the time to test all the scenarios - because if you change your media queries to `em` then you also need to consider changing container `max-widths`, and, I would presume, a number of other values that are using `px` - mixing your values is not a good idea and could cause unforeseen headaches in the long run.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/17403

If you are like me, and you are using Bootstrap because

1. it's thoroughly tested
2. it allows you to build websites within a
   short time-frame and on a low budget

then I would suggest just leaving it at the default `px` values and hope they will reconsider this feature with Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you exactly what's wrong. Line `42` of `_breakpoints.scss` is:

> @return if($next, breakpoint-min($next, $breakpoints) - .02px, null);

If you want to use `em` make sure you replace all instances of `px`.

Comment: Yes I understood that thanks. I just wanted to avoid editing the original Bootstrap files but it seems that is not possible. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Please consider upvoting my latest answer if you agree, or adding a comment if you disagree.